# Only return the response status from a axios GET request?

Tags: node.js, axios, playwright

I`m writing tests in playwright where I check if all the links on my web page are valid.

I'm using Axios to get the responses and because I have a lot of links I want to expedite the tests as much as possible, so I want to receive only the status response code from Axios without the response data, is this in any way possible with Axios or maybe to use another library to achieve this?

Comment: why don't you send an empty object as a response?

Comment: Hmm dont know what exactly you mean, but Im using axios to call the URL`s and getting response back, how can I send an empty object ? Sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: I thought that you can modify the backend code 
you only want to see what status code you will get when you connect to these links with axios, it really depends on how the backend sends you the response. if the backend has the same response structure for every route you can set something for it
if not it's gonna be a little bit hard.

Answer (score 0):

I used axios.head() request, which only returns the response header and not the data, but had to add to use:

### axios options: decompress: false// default true

> `decompress` indicates whether or not the response body should be
> decompressed  automatically. If set to `true` will also remove the
> 'content-encoding' header  from the responses objects of all
> decompressed responses